# How to handle per-customer customizations on Azure API REST

Tags: azure, api, rest, deployment, azure-web-app-service

We have a REST API hosted on App Services. The API is stateless, every method receives an API key and depending on that we connect to one data source or another (the API is common to every customer but they have their own databases). The API and data structure is common for all customers.

Now we have some unique, per-customer requests involving custom fields or features only present in certain customer databases, these should only work on certain customers.

Question: what is the best way of handling such scenario?

- Everything on the same API solution, include custom code when requested and deploy the whole thing to the core API endpoint.

  - Easier solution but risky since we could introduce bugs on core API working on customizations. All custom methods will be visible and accessible to all customers.
- One core API, One custom API with all different custom methods for different customers.

  - Regular customers will interact with core API, all custom methods (and only custom methods) grouped in a different API with its own endpoint.
  - Customizations won't disrupt the core API.
  - Some customers will have to interact with 2 different endpoints (core and custom)
- A copy of the core API + custom methods deployed to a new API instance with its own endpoint for those customers with special needs?

  - Only one endpoint per customer: regular users will reach the core API, other customers will have their own API endpoint will all: core and custom methods
  - How to handle changes in core API when every custom API has a copy of it.

Am I completely missing the point?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create **Products** in APIM.

Firstly, if you have just one API, break down your API to the smallest set of APIs where there is no redundancy between two APIs. You will be mapping these API sets to Products.

Next create one APIM product for each client (or one product for each set of one or more clients who will be using the same set of APIs). After creating the products, only map the APIs relevant to those clients in that product.
[image]
After creating the product, go to the subscriptions tab and create new subscription keys for the scope of your product. Your clients can now use the product subscription key to authenticate with their products and other APIs not available in that product wont be visible or accessible for them.
[image]

For more information on setting up APIM products, see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-add-products?tabs=azure-portal

Since one API can be used in one or more products and one product can be composed of one or more APIs, and clients only have accessibility for the APIs in a product they have the key to, you can easily manage your APIs without redundancy or complexity.

Comment: Nice. Thanks. Do you know If I can associate a subscription to a client secret (a connection string for example). All customizations will have static connection strings but the core "product" will connect to one DB or another depending on the customer.